# On the shortest vectors of lattices generated by powers of generator matrices

Tags: euclidean-lattices

Let $B\in\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ generate a rank-$r$ lattice $\mathcal L_1\subseteq\mathbb Z^n$ and let $B^k\in\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ generate lattice $\mathcal L_k\subseteq\mathbb Z^n$ assuming $\mathcal L_k$ is rank-$r$ lattice.

1. Is there a relation between the $r$ shortest vectors and fundamental volumes of $\mathcal L_i$ and $\mathcal L_j$ at $i\neq j$?
2. Do maximal lattices in $\mathcal L_i\otimes\mathcal L_j$ have any relation to $\mathcal L_i$ and $\mathcal L_j$ and the $n$ shortest vectors in the lattices $\mathcal L_i$ and $\mathcal L_j$?

Comment: Hello, 1. if the $n$ shortest lattice vectors $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ are linearly independent, then the form a basis of the lattice or equivalently the fundamental cell. Hence, $\det(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is the fundamental volume of the lattice.

Comment: @Jochen correct